# Can I use Google map API in my Navigation app but not for navigation feature?

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I've read Google Map API Terms of use, section 10.4.c.iii
I know that I cannot use Google Map/Places API for real-time navigation.

I only use Google API for finding the current place (Geocoding/Reverse Geocoding). 
The data for navigation comes from another data source, I built it myself, not direction data from Google. I'm totally not using Google's data for real-time navigation. However, I started a Google Map Android app and need to draw the route on the Map Surface for the simulation.

I am not clear at this point that I can use Google API for my app or not.
Please advice. Thank you.